# Android Studio: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'. >

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I need help, Im new in Android Studio and Im getting this error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForRelease'.
com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/database/DatabaseUtilsCompat.class
```

Here is my build.gradle file and hope this can help:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app_name.vallic.hr"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 25
        multiDexEnabled true

        ndk {
            moduleName "player_shared"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }


    }

    configurations {
        all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
        all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    }

    sourceSets.main {
        jni.srcDirs = []// <-- disable automatic ndk-build call
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services:+') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
        compile files('libs/dagger-1.2.2.jar')
        compile files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
        compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
        compile files('libs/support-v4-19.0.1.jar')
        compile('com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1')
    }
}
```

Comment: check my updated answer.

Comment: hi., where can i change the multidex library intialization?

Comment: Hi, already changed it, I appreciate youre help but still got the same error.

Comment: why should you use compile files('libs/support-v4-19.0.1.jar') ? It is a very very old version.

Comment: Hi gabrielle, what should I do then? update?

Comment: You can use the latest version, and nineoldandroids is not longer supported (because there is no reason to use it today)

Comment: i think i forgot to update some in my sdk tools. thanks for reminding and ill see if it will work

Answer (score 0):

`multidex` also having `support v4` library classes, You already included the v4 library separately.

So you have to exclude `support v4` module from `multidex` library.

change your `mulitdex` library initialization like this.

```
    compile ('com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'){
            exclude module: 'support-v4'
        }
```

You dependencies initialization should be like this.

```
dependencies {
    compile('com.google.android.gms:play-services:+') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile files('libs/dagger-1.2.2.jar')
    compile files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
    compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
    compile files('libs/support-v4-19.0.1.jar')
    compile('com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'){
    exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
}
```

Hope it helps:)

Comment: hi., where can i change the multidex library intialization?

Comment: See my answer, copy the complete dependencies code and replace with yours. That's it.